# CosmosDB create compound unique index error

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I wanted to create a compound unique index using 2 fields, but one of those has a path to some inner field like `evaluated.rut`. But I got an error:

[image]

I don't get the error, in MongoDB I had created index like that, but I can't now in CosmosDB, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the nested path is not an array, the support for this is coming out very soon using the value `EnableUniqueCompoundNestedDocs` in the capabilities property array for a Cosmos DB databaseAccounts resource in ARM.

This is not yet publicly available. If you'd like to try today you can open a support ticket and ask this capability be added your Cosmos account. You can also DM me on Twitter (see my SO profile) and send me your Cosmos account name and I can request it for you.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/indexing) for what is not supported and its limitations.

Comment: Link-only answers are not valid answers. If anything, this should be a comment (and you have enough rep to do so)